# return boolean with forEach in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want check my Array, if I get 3 , I want break my forEach and return true o false if it isn't true.

but I get undefined when I push 3 in my html-

```
 let errorSave: boolean = this.checkParams();

 console.log("errorSave" , errorSave); // UNDEFINED

 checkParams() {
        let errorSave = this.params.forEach(element => {
            if (element.origin === 3) {
               return true;
            }
        });
        return errorSave;
    }
```

Comment: forEach can't do that. Here's the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach. You want some(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try using `find`?

```
checkParams() {
    return !!this.params.find(element => element.origin === 3);
}
```

Comment: some() would be much more appropriate.

Comment: @EduBw this has nothing to do with Angular. It's pure TypeScript/JavaScript. That's important: if you're looking for how to use forEach in the Angular documentation, you won't find anything. You need to read the API documentation of JavaScript arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf) instead of foreach clause.

```
array=[1,2,3];

return this.array.indexOf(3)>-1;
```